# Call jquery function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call the logic in the click method in my javascript code. How can I call this method?

```js
(function($) {
  window.numberArray = [],
    window.phoneNumber = '',
    window.updateDisplay,
    window.numberDisplayEl,
    window.inCallModeActive,
    window.dialpadButton = $('div#dialpad li'),
    window.dialpadCase = $('div#dialpad'),
    window.clearButton = $('#actions .clear'),
    window.callButton = $('#actions .call'),
    window.actionButtons = $('#actions'),
    window.skipButton = $('#actions .skip'),
    window.numberDisplayEl = $('#numberDisplay input');


  $('div#actions li.clear').click(function() {
    debugger;
    enableCallButton();
    enableDialButton();
    clearPhoneNumber();
    removeReadOnlyInput();
    changeHangUpIntoClear();
    updateDisplay();
    checkDisplayEl();
    disableInCallInterface();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Create a separate function which wraps that logic, then call it in the click handler and anywhere else you need in your JS code. Also you should avoid polluting the `window` namespace and using globals. What you're doing there is really bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a global var, that contains the functions you need, from inside the code.

```
//The object with the functions
var functions = {};
(function($) {
    window.numberArray = [],
    window.phoneNumber = '',
    window.updateDisplay,
    window.numberDisplayEl,
    window.inCallModeActive,
    window.dialpadButton = $('div#dialpad li'),
    window.dialpadCase = $('div#dialpad'),
    window.clearButton = $('#actions .clear'),
    window.callButton = $('#actions .call'),
    window.actionButtons = $('#actions'),
    window.skipButton = $('#actions .skip'),
    window.numberDisplayEl = $('#numberDisplay input');

    //Here you set the property action with the function call
    functions.action = function (){ 
        debugger;
        enableCallButton();
        enableDialButton();
        clearPhoneNumber();
        removeReadOnlyInput();
        changeHangUpIntoClear();
        updateDisplay();
        checkDisplayEl();
        disableInCallInterface();
    }

    $('div#actions li.clear').click(function() {
        functions.action();
    });
})(jQuery);
```